# Toggle Menu when closed not change icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a toggle menu

```
     <button class="menu"
              onclick="menu(this),this.classList.toggle('opened');this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', this.classList.contains('opened'))">
```

And I apply css if it is opened

Where menu:

```
function menu(event) {
    if($(event).hasClass('active')) {
        $(event).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(event).addClass('active');
    }
}
```

This works, so If I click on menu it is opened and I change the icon , and if I click another time the menu is closed and the icon returns as at the beginning.

My problem is if I click on the menu, it change the icon, but If I don't click another time in the menu but in another page, the icon remains equals.

So for example

MENU: with Icon1

I click on menu Icon1->Icon2.
I close menu Icon2->Icon1

I click on menu Icon1->Icon2
If I click in another part (for example in another page) the menu is closed but Icon is Icon2

Comment: By saying another page are you talking about a concurrent tab? Or href page? Or same page but different section?

Comment: The problem is because you've only bound the logic which updates the CSS/icon to the click of the `button` element. Clicking anywhere else doesn't run that code. You need to restructure the JS and HTML to genericise the code which toggles your menu. Could you please include all the HTML and CSS for the menu itself so we can see how best to fix the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes the problem is this one, that I have the JS linked onClick..